# Keybindings: Is there a `when` clause for the index of the focused editor in its group, or if it's the last?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use keyboard shortcuts to cycle through tabs using `workbench.action.nextEditorInGroup` and `workbench.action.previousEditorInGroup` which works great for me except that they "wrap".  In other words, if you are on the first tab of an editor group and you execute `workbench.action.previousEditorInGroup` it will focus the last editor in the group.  There doesn't seem to be a setting for preventing this behavior (though if you know of one that would solve my problem!), so I'm hoping to achieve it through the `when` clause in the keybindings.

I found `activeEditorGroupIndex` and `activeEditorGroupLast`, but I have not found a similar clause for the editor index.  Does anyone know of one?

Here's my current bindings:

```js
    { "key": "ctrl+.", "command": "workbench.action.nextEditorInGroup", "when": "editorFocus" },
    { "key": "ctrl+,", "command": "workbench.action.previousEditorInGroup", "when": "editorFocus" },
```

What I'd like is something like:

```js
    { "key": "ctrl+.", "command": "workbench.action.nextEditorInGroup", "when": "editorFocus && !activeEditorLast" },
    { "key": "ctrl+,", "command": "workbench.action.previousEditorInGroup", "when": "editorFocus && !activeEditorIndex == 0" },
```

Comment: I see a `groupEditorsCount` which gives you the number of editors in the active group.  But I don't see anything with an editorIndex/Count/First/Last to compare it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These new context keys are in v1.66:

```
activeEditorIsFirstInGroup  
activeEditorIsLastInGroup
```

> New context keys were added to figure out if an editor is first or
> last in an editor group:
>
> - `activeEditorIsFirstInGroup`- Whether the active editor is the first one in its group.
> - `activeEditorIsLastInGroup`- Whether the active editor is the last one in its group.

see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_66.md#new-context-keys-for-editors

I would think these keybindings should work for you:

```
{ "key": "ctrl+.", "command": "workbench.action.nextEditorInGroup", "when": "editorFocus && !activeEditorIsLastInGroup" },  

{ "key": "ctrl+,", "command": "workbench.action.previousEditorInGroup", "when": "editorFocus && !activeEditorIsFirstInGroup" }
```